# QTableView with QWidget as QStyledItemDelegate

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm coding a Python CRUD app that shows radiosondes on a map and a QTableView. I'm using QStyledItemDelegate to set an editor and regex validator for each column and it is working great. But for the geometry column I would like to parse the binary data and show it on a custom form (lat, lng, elevation), be able to edit them and if clicked OK encode them back to WKB format and update the data.

[image]

When I click OK the filed is not updated, instead it becomes empty. If I try to edit after that any other cell nothing happens and if I try to edit that exact cell the app crashes. The same happens if I click Cancel.

The setData method returns True and the data in the DB gets updated.

I tried with dataChanged.emit() on the QSqlTableModel and also with update() method on the QTableView.

main2.py:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QStyledItemDelegate
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from shapely import wkb, wkt
import folium
import io



class Ui_RadioSondes(object):

    def setupUi(self, RadioSondes):
        self.centerCoord = (44.071800, 17.578125)

        RadioSondes.setObjectName("RadioSondes")
.
.
.
        self.tableView_2.setItemDelegate(ValidatedItemDelegate())
.
.
.
    
class ValidatedItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, widget, option, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return 0
        if index.column() == 0: #only on the cells in the first column
            editor = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(widget)
            validator = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(QtCore.QRegExp('[\w]{1,10}'), editor)
            editor.setValidator(validator)
            return editor
        if index.column() == 2:
            editor = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(widget)
            editor.setMaximum(360)
            editor.setMinimum(1)
            return editor
.
.
.
        if index.column() == 9:
            self.form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.form)
            self.formLayout.setVerticalSpacing(12)
            self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
            ###__________ Latitude__________###
            self.latLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.form)
            self.latLabel.setObjectName("latLabel")
            self.latLabel.setText("Latitude")
            self.latLabel.adjustSize()
            self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.latLabel)
            self.latEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.form)
            # lineEdit.textChanged.connect(validateFields)
            self.latEdit.setObjectName("latEdit")
            self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.latEdit)
            ###__________ Longitude__________###
            self.lngLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.form)
            self.lngLabel.setObjectName("lngLabel")
            self.lngLabel.setText("Longitude")
            self.lngLabel.adjustSize()
            self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.lngLabel)
            self.lngEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.form)
            # lineEdit.textChanged.connect(validateFields)
            self.lngEdit.setObjectName("lngEdit")
            self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lngEdit)
            ###__________ Elevation__________###
            self.elevationLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.form)
            self.elevationLabel.setObjectName("elevationLabel")
            self.elevationLabel.setText("Elevation")
            self.elevationLabel.adjustSize()
            self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.elevationLabel)
            self.elevationEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.form)
            # lineEdit.textChanged.connect(validateFields)
            self.elevationEdit.setObjectName("elevationEdit")
            self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.elevationEdit)

            self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self.form)
            self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
            self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
            self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
            self.formLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)

            self.form.resize(200, 300)

            self.prevData = index.data()
            self.index = index
            self.widget = widget

            self.model = self.widget.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().objModel
            self.t_view = self.widget.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().tableView_2

            data = self.model.data(self.index)
            geomWkb = wkb.loads(bytes.fromhex(data))
            self.latEdit.setText(str(geomWkb.x))
            self.lngEdit.setText(str(geomWkb.y))
            self.elevationEdit.setText(str(geomWkb.z))

            self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.generateGeom)
            self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.cancelGeomEdit)
            return self.form
        return super(ValidatedItemDelegate, self).createEditor(widget, option, index)

    def generateGeom(self):
        print(self.latEdit.text())
        print(self.lngEdit.text())
        print(self.elevationEdit.text())

        geomStr = "POINT Z (" + self.latEdit.text() + " " + self.lngEdit.text() + " " + self.elevationEdit.text() + ")"
        geom = wkt.loads(geomStr)
        geomWkb = wkb.dumps(geom, hex=True, srid=4326)

        try:
            self.model.setData(self.index, geomWkb, Qt.EditRole)

            self.form.close()
            #self.t_view.update()
        except AssertionError as error:
            print(error)

    def cancelGeomEdit(self):
        self.form.destroy(destroyWindow=True)
```

Here is the whole code on GitHub: https://github.com/draugnim/pyCrud

**EDIT**

I managed to get it working by calling `self.model.selet()` at the end of generateGeom() and cancelGeomEdit(). But still if I click on the X button and close the form the edited cell becomes blank, also this and all other cells become uneditable.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item delegate uses the editor's *user* property, which is considered the main default property of a Qt object. For QLineEdit it's `text()`, for a QSpinBox it's `value()`, etc.

If you want to provide a custom, advanced editor, the solution is to create a subclass with a *custom* user property.
Note that the Qt internal way of dealing with item data is a bit strict on types, and since PyQt doesn't expose the QVariant class, the only option is to use a suitable type. For you case, [QVector3D](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector3d.html) is a perfect choice.

Then, using an *external* window is a bit tricky, as delegates are normally supposed to be simple field editors that exist *inside* the view. To work around that, the following must be considered:

- the editor must notify the delegate that the inserted data has been accepted, and it must destroy itself whenever it's closed;
- key press events must be *ignored* in the filter (return `False`), so that the editor can properly handle them;
- focus and hide events must ignored too, as the delegate by default tries to update the model when the editor has not been "rejected" but it loses focus or is hidden;
- the geometry must be set using the parent's top level `window()`, and the `updateEditorGeometry()` must be ignored as the delegate would try to update the geometry whenever the view is shown again after being hidden or it's resized;

Since the given code is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I'll provide a generic example of the concept.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from random import randrange

class CoordinateEditor(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    submit = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtWidgets.QWidget)
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)

        layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        self.latitudeSpin = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(minimum=-90, maximum=90)
        layout.addRow('Latitude', self.latitudeSpin)
        self.longitudeSpin = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(minimum=-180, maximum=180)
        layout.addRow('Longitude', self.longitudeSpin)
        self.elevationSpin = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(minimum=-100, maximum=100)
        layout.addRow('Elevation', self.elevationSpin)

        buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(
            QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        layout.addRow(buttonBox)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        self.finished.connect(self.deleteLater)

    def accept(self):
        super().accept()
        self.submit.emit(self)

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(QtGui.QVector3D, user=True)
    def coordinateData(self):
        return QtGui.QVector3D(
            self.longitudeSpin.value(), 
            self.latitudeSpin.value(), 
            self.elevationSpin.value()
        )

    @coordinateData.setter
    def coordinateData(self, data):
        self.longitudeSpin.setValue(data.x())
        self.latitudeSpin.setValue(data.y())
        self.elevationSpin.setValue(data.z())

    def showEvent(self, event):
        if not event.spontaneous():
            geo = self.geometry()
            geo.moveCenter(self.parent().window().geometry().center())
            self.setGeometry(geo)
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.latitudeSpin.setFocus)


class DialogDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        if index.column() == 1:
            editor = CoordinateEditor(parent)
            editor.submit.connect(self.commitData)
            return editor
        else:
            return super().createEditor(parent, option, index)

    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        if index.column() == 1 and index.data() is not None:
            coords = index.data()
            option.text = '{:.02f}, {:.02f}, {:.02f}'.format(
                coords.y(), coords.x(), coords.z())

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if isinstance(source, CoordinateEditor):
            if event.type() in (event.KeyPress, event.FocusOut, event.Hide):
                return False
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        if not isinstance(editor, CoordinateEditor):
            super().updateEditorGeometry(editor, option, index)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    test.setItemDelegate(DialogDelegate(test))
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 2)
    for row in range(10):
        coordItem = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        coords = QtGui.QVector3D(
            randrange(-180, 181), 
            randrange(-90, 91), 
            randrange(-100, 101))
        coordItem.setData(coords, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        model.appendRow((
            QtGui.QStandardItem('Data {}'.format(row + 1)), 
            coordItem, 
        ))
    test.setModel(model)
    test.resizeColumnsToContents()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer and example!

Comment: @eyllanesc I was going to make an minimal reproducible example but I couldn't figure out how to make it work without a database or how to effectively share the DB, so I decided to put the code and DB dump file on a GitHub repo for anyone willing to take a deeper look. 

I would appreciate it very much if someone could clarify to me how to approach this, so my future questions don't lack a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Draugnim: well, consider my example. Is your question about data retrieval from the database? No, so why bother about it? As you can see, I created an example based on totally random data (I only ensured that they have the proper ranges), because the problem was about the *editing* of the data, and only for a single column, so the database dump is completely useless for this. A MRE should be focused on the actual issue alone, anything else is just a distraction.